# When the lunar module ascent stage launched to take astronauts back to the command module, how long was the launch window?

Tags: the-moon, rendezvous, launch-window

[This](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jared%20owen%20apollo%20missions&t=brave&iax=videos&ia=videos&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dqt_xoCXLXnI) excellent animation says the launch must happen at "just the right time", but how long was the actual launch window, how precisely (how many seconds or minutes) did the launch need to be timed within in order to rendezvous with the command & service module as planned?

Also, how was that timing orchestrated? How did they know the location and orbital trajectory of the CSM in order to time the launch to achieve a successful rendezvous?

Comment: I think the "how was that timing orchestrated?" is a lot more interesting and isn't addressed by the other question or its answer (which isn't much more than link-only anyway). To avoid being a duplicate why not emphasize the second part of your question, mention the linked answer doesn't address it and adjust your title accordingly. *Welcome to Space!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an answer about launch windows on Space Exploration Stack Exchange [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33723/launch-window-for-the-apollo-lunar-module). Basically, there was a launch window of a few minutes every two hours for optimum rendezvous with the Command Module, but in an emergency the LEM could just launch into lunar orbit at any time and then rely on the CSM (which had much larger fuel reserves) to perform orbital manoeuvres to rendezvous with it.

Both the LEM and the CSM had onboard guidance and navigation computers, and the LEM had a rendezvous radar that tracked the CSM while it was above the horizon. Also, as a fall-back, Mission Control were tracking the CSM when it was not behind the Moon.

For much, much more information about all aspects of Apollo guidance and navigation, read the excellent *Sunburst and Luminary* by [Don Eyles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Eyles)

Comment: The coelliptic rendezvous system used contained an intermediate phasing stage, so it was not necessary for the CM to pick up the LM. The LM could launch at any time and coast until conditions were right for it to reach the CM.

Comment: @Innovine, "any time", subject to the available electricity, oxygen, CO2 scrubbing, and cooling water.  A worst-case launch would require 48 hours of phasing time, and the ascent module would typically have only 12-24 hours of consumables on board.

Comment: That'd be fine with one astronaut on board